# How to merge result from multiple tables in efficient way Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have to merge results from multiple tables in Laravel. Currently I am using the following way:

```
public function getMachines(Request $request) {
        $vendor_id = Auth::id();
        $ml_8_machine=ML8Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
        $ml_16_machine=ML16Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
        $ml_32_machine=ML32Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
        $ml_64_machine=ML64Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
        $ml_96_machine=ML96Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
        $ml_128_machine=ML128Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
        $machines = collect($ml_8_machine)
                        ->merge($ml_16_machine)
                        ->merge($ml_32_machine)
                        ->merge($ml_64_machine)
                        ->merge($ml_96_machine)
                        ->merge($ml_128_machine);
        return view('vendor.machines', compact('machines'));      
    }
```

I am looking for an efficient way to do the query and merge result in one collection.

Comment: are these ML?Machine  table have same columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your columns are the same, 
you can use `unionAll` to merge the records. This will reduce the IO cost:

```php
public function getMachines(Request $request) {
        $vendor_id = Auth::id();
        $ml_8_machine=ML8Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->select('column1', 'column2'...);
        $ml_16_machine=ML16Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->select('column1', 'column2'...);
        $ml_32_machine=ML32Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->select('column1', 'column2'...);
        $ml_64_machine=ML64Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->select('column1', 'column2'...);
        $ml_96_machine=ML96Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->select('column1', 'column2'...);
        $ml_128_machine=ML128Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->select('column1', 'column2'...);
        $machines = $ml_8_machine->unionAll($ml_16_machine)
                        ->unionAll($ml_32_machine)
                        ->unionAll($ml_64_machine)
                        ->unionAll($ml_96_machine)
                        ->unionAll($ml_128_machine)
                        ->get();
        return view('vendor.machines', compact('machines'));      
    }
```

Remember, you need to keep each columns as same order as others.

And you can add `paginate()` on this query too:

```php
$machines = $ml_8_machine->unionAll($ml_16_machine)
                        ->unionAll($ml_32_machine)
                        ->unionAll($ml_64_machine)
                        ->unionAll($ml_96_machine)
                        ->unionAll($ml_128_machine)
                        ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe One of these ways may help you

```
$vendor_id = Auth::id();

$ml_8_machine=ML8Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
$ml_16_machine=ML16Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
$ml_32_machine=ML32Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
$ml_64_machine=ML64Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
$ml_96_machine=ML96Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)->get();
$machines = ML128Machine::where('vendor_id','=',$vendor_id)
        ->union($ml_8_machine)
        ->union($ml_16_machine)
        ->union($ml_32_machine)
        ->union($ml_64_machine)
        ->union($ml_96_machine)
        ->get();

return view('vendor.machines', compact('machines'));
```

or use raw query [methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods)

```
(SELECT * from ml_8_machine where `vendor_id` = '?')
UNION
(SELECT * from ml_16_machine where `vendor_id` = '?')
```

or

```
SELECT * from ml_8_machine, ml_16_machine where `ml_8_machine.vendor_id` = '?' AND `ml_16_machine.vendor_id` = '?'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [collapse()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-collapse) method

```
$collection = collect([$ml_8_machine, $ml_16_machine, $ml_32_machine, $ml_64_machine, $ml_96_machine, $ml_128_machine]);

$machines = $collection->collapse();

//dump($machines);

return view('vendor.machines', compact('machines'));
```